# Android studio setting layout up like this

Tags: java, android, layout, android-studio

I've tried everything I can think of but can't get this layout working. It's a ListView that list matches in a row.

Row one is first match, and next row is second match, and so on.  I don't don't mind the green strokes and borders.

Is it even possible?

**See the deisgn here:** [image]

Comment: You have missing image.

Comment: Hmm i added it as a link, does it work? :)

Comment: I think it should be a achievable. Except for the text badge it should be easy to get everything in place. For the text badge you probably have to define the height for some components to get it in the right place either through some smart usage of frame layout or relative layout. So the right side ends up a slightly bit more complicated.

Comment: I'd recommend creating an object that holds the 4 text values and the two integers. Then you can make an adapter to list all these objects (I'd use data-binding for the adapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example implementation, it does however use negative margins, to overlap the thing I called badge.[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cdcdcd"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/score"
        android:layout_below="@+id/badge"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="0 vs 7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/badge"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/badge"
        android:id="@+id/right_table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/score"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 2"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
        android:text="Badge"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To alternate the background simply set the background in `getView` in your adapter.

Comment: Thanks alot!! it works like a boss!! Now i just need to make it list all data... :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom adapter that fills the ListView (better use RecyclerView & an Adapter with ViehHolder), this row layout is taken from my own project, not exactly what you requested, but you'll get the idea. Just comment for further information.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_player1"
        android:text="player1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textV_vs"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textV_vs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_player2"
        android:text="player2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textV_vs"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textV_vs"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textV_vs" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_vs"
        android:text="vs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textV_points1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_points1"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textV_player1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textV_player1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textV_player1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_points2"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textV_player2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textV_player2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textV_player2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV_vspoints"
        android:text=":"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textV_vs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That looks great.. But i cant see to get the numbers to beside the vs insted of under it.. Is it because that its not possible to make a view where the two sides own 40% each of the view, and the middle field, with the numbers and vs only own 20%?

Comment: Just add the attribute
        `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textV_vs"` the left number textview, same attribute with right for the right. To get some feeling for this, try playing with in the `design` tab and drag&drop your views.